# Which lifecycle event is called when a screen appears?

Tags: javascript, react-native, lifecycle, react-navigation

Suppose I have two screens:

- Screen A
- Screen B

I am initially landed on <kbd>Screen A</kbd>. When I click on a `Button` I navigate to <kbd>Screen B</kbd>. When I press `Back Button`, I am again navigated to <kbd>Screen A</kbd>.

I want to call an action creator when I am navigated to <kbd>Screen A</kbd> as mentioned in above scenario.

I just want to know that which lifecycle event will be called every time when a screen is presented.

Isn't there some event like `componentWillAppear()`?

**Note:** I am using `react-native` with `react-navigation` for navigation.

Comment: *which lifecycle event will be called every time when a screen is presented* **render**. But you can use `componentDidMount`

Comment: @Rajesh Are you sure that componentDidMount will always be called when I goBack to view?

Comment: If the component is rendered again, yes. If you are using css to show/hide, then not sure.

Comment: @Rajesh I am not using css but I use react-navigation to navigate between the screens

Comment: Just check, on back button, if the screenA's render is called ot not. If not, you might have to pass a callback for back button.

Comment: @Rajesh Thanks for helping. I got my answer.

Comment: In Stack Navigation, when you go from screen A to Screen B, A never gets unmounted and hence doesn't hvae to mount again when it comes back from B.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This can now be done with plain react navigation via their listeners:

In your Component A:

```
componentDidMount = () => {
  this._componentFocused();

  this._sub = this.props.navigation.addListener(
    'didFocus',
    this._componentFocused
  );
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  this._sub.remove();
}

_componentFocused = () => {
  this.setState({dataToShow});
}
```

[React Navigation docs - Lifecycle](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-prop.html#addlistener-subscribe-to-updates-to-navigation-lifecycle)

Answer (score 1):

When you navigate from one screen to another, the first screen will not be unmounted, but still on the stack, just hide in the background.

What you need might be `componentDidFocus`, but it's currently in design not avaiable yet, see [react-native open issue #51](https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/issues/51).

You can try this alternative way: [react-navigation-addons](https://github.com/satya164/react-navigation-addons). With this you can have events `focus` & `blur` which may suit your needs.

Comment: Thanks. I will take a look at react-navigation-addons. Once the timeout is finished, I will mark this answer as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

If you use react-native-navigation, you can listen for appearance events: https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/screen-api?id=listen-to-visibility-events-globally

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I do not use react-native-navigation. I use react-navigation for my navigation purposes.