# Problems with re-render component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

> I have the next situation,
>
> I build a react native app, using design patter:
>   Container-Presentational.
>
> ***Focus on the problem:***  When I update props, in component A, I need that the B component change too, when I switch the screen to this
>   B component, I need B component re-render with this new props.
>
> You need to know I am using redux to storage the props, and this
>   component shared navigation.
>
> *The main problem is that I cant found one life cycle method where I can re-render component with this new props because the component was
>   rendered, I can´t join in anyone life cycle method.*

I can't share the code I'm sorry, but the idea is this:

Having component A and B and these depend on a  that depending on their value will show one thing or another.

**Example**: When I change the value of the picker in component B and then I go to component A, the value of the picker is still maintained.
but the information that should be displayed in component A is still the one that corresponds to the previous value in the picker and not to the current value.

Until now I have been able to solve it in the following way but I don't know if it is the optimal one.
inside the onValueChange of the picker, where I do the ditpatch to update the data of the component itself, I also do the ditpach of the other component.

Comment: Can you please share the component code?

Comment: you can use the navigation life cycle. you can see this answer(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47627663/which-lifecycle-event-is-called-when-a-screen-appears/51143799)