# State does not unmount when changing screens and opens randomly ( react-navigation - firebase - react native-maps - giftedcha )

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-gifted-chat

The screen states do not reset when navigating between screens.

Screen A: Map ( Main Screen ) Screen B : Map filters

When the user logs in he sees the main screen - Screen A - where on componentdidmount setState with the users in the firebase realtime db. To filter the map he goes to Screen B where he sets the filters, and the filters are saved to firebase. After the filters are saved he goes back to screen A, but the users in from the initial state are the same and to view the filtered list the user needs to restart the app.

Having the same problem with gifted chat library and firebase when a user sends a message the chat screen opens randomly on the other users' app and reopens even if the users are not chatting.

Tried in both situations to put isMonted = true on componentdidmount and set it to false when leaving the screens, but with no success.

Tried to setState when leaving the screen to all initial states to false, also with no luck.

All the screens are on the same navigation stack.

Using : -expo -firebase -react native navigation -react native maps -giftedchat

Is any way to unmount the states when the user leaves the screen and prevents the screen from opening randomly?

Tried : [Which lifecycle event is called when a screen appears?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47627663/which-lifecycle-event-is-called-when-a-screen-appears) but the data remained the same

Comment: when you are navigating back try this.props.navigation.push rather than this.props.navigation.navigate

Comment: The push method worked on updating the state, but now the markers on Screen A are causing some flickering

Comment: umm, dont know about that since no code is there, but i guess you got what you were ooking for

Answer (score 0):

From the docs :

> The reset action wipes the whole navigation state and replaces it with
>   the result of several actions.

```
import { StackActions, NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation';

const resetAction = StackActions.reset({
  index: 0,
  actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Screen B' })],
});
this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction);
```